# Groovy: Timeduration-Subtraction evaluated from string

Tags: string, date, groovy, subtraction, evaluate

My script reads a string from a file and evaluates it to work as TimeDuration within TimeCategory. If the string starts with a "-" it throws an Exception.

My reduced script:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory;

String string = "-1.day"
Date now = new Date()
use(TimeCategory)
{
    def x = new Date() + evaluate(string)
    println x
}
```

Throws:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.time.Duration.negative() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: notify()
```

At the moment my solution would be this:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory;

String string = "-1.day"
Date now = new Date()
use(TimeCategory)
{
    def x
    if(string.startsWith("-"))
    {
        string = string.substring(1)
        x = now - evaluate(string)
    }
    else
    {
        x = now + evaluate(string)
    }
    println x
}
```

It could although do the following. But... i dont like it. I'm not sure about the consequence (will it work with different time units? "-1.day+2.hours-3.minutes"):

```
String prestring = "-1.day"
String string = "0.day$prestring"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order the operations are evaluated in:

`-1.day` is equivalent to `-(1.day)`, or `(1.day).negative()`

To solve this, you can apply parentheses to evaluate the minus operator first:

`(-1).day`

Another solution is to add a `negative()` method to the `Duration` class.

```
Duration.metaClass.negative = { -> 
    new Duration(-delegate.days, 
                 -delegate.hours, 
                 -delegate.minutes, 
                 -delegate.seconds, 
                 -delegate.millis) 
}
```

Comment: Thank. I'll use the parentheses. I want to use it "natural", not to programm around.